# Here I am copying data of table to another table .whenever I use hardcode for id value then it will work and other sccenario it is not working

Tags: php

In this Php query I am copying data from one table to another table.
In first table column names are Worker_Type,No_of_Worker,Date_From,Date_To and another table's columns are Worker_Type,No_of_Worker,Date_From,Date_To,id .

```
<?php
$host='localhost';
$uname='';
$pwd='';
$db="client_supplier";

$con = mysql_connect($host,$uname,$pwd) or die("connection failed");
mysql_select_db($db,$con) or die("db selection failed");

$id=$_REQUEST['id'];
$Worker_Type=$_REQUEST['Worker_Type'];
$No_of_Worker=$_REQUEST['No_of_Worker'];
$Date_From=$_REQUEST['Date_From'];
$Date_To=$_REQUEST['Date_To'];


$flag['code']=0;

if($r=mysql_query("INSERT INTO Interested(Worker_Type,No_of_Worker,Date_From,Date_To) SELECT Worker_Type,No_of_Worker,Date_From,Date_To FROM Supplier_data WHERE id ='$id' ",$con))
{
    $flag['code']=1;
    echo"hi";
}

print(json_encode($flag));
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: This  query i am using in my andoid project it is not working.

Comment: when i change the value of $id to 1 then it is working...

Comment: you can check result from this link  http://hcm4qatar.com/PHP/interest.php

Comment: Time to reset your username and password. You've expose your credentials. You also are open to SQL injections.

Comment: are you sure you are receiving id by `$id=$_REQUEST['id']` can you see the id when you echo $id for testing purpose?

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? *What* isn't working? The query will return true (as in your if statement will pass) as long as the query didn't have an error. Even if there were no rows found as that is still a valid query result. If I had to guess what you are trying to do, you want to return the number of rows found, not just whether or not the query failed.

Comment: echo $id does not print any result it is blank .

Comment: Please note, just editing the credentials out of the question body will not do. Whilst the chance is slim that someone will be able to find your Web site, and login to the database using the credentials provided.. it's still a possibility. We can review edits to see what has changed between the two versions & roll back if necessary. Change your database credentials.

Comment: I changed my credentials of database Daryl Gill.